# How can we create a color scales for excel using R?

Tags: r, statistics, xlsx, xlconnect

I want to create a color scale based on the input values from an excel spreadsheet.The required output is a color scaled cells in the excel sheet based on the values  which is programmed in R.I tried through XLConnect but haven't yet found a suitable solution.

thanks & Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have to be much more specific, including self contained example code of what you did, what did not work, what the errors where that you received.

Comment: You're almost certainly doing things the hard way, but at the very least tell us whether you need to know the actual values generated in `R` to set the ranges of the Excel cells' conditional formatting.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft , Sorry for the late reply. Yes your understanding is correct , i need to know the exact values in R to set the ranges of the excel cells.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thanks. I am actually new to using R and have been exploring all the function and packages. What i tried was loading an xls file and putting a heatmap based on the ranges. But the problem is that this is device output which i will not be  able to save in an excel sheet.

Comment: Time to back up: what is your desired result?  It's easy to generate a heatmap, with or without the numbers displayed, in `R` .  Unless someones aiming a gun at your head, you shouldn't use Excel in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The xlsx package allows using RGB-colors for Fill(). E.g.

```
fg <- rgb(100, 50, 50, max = 100)
bg <- "black"
style <- CellStyle(wb) + Fill(foregroundColor = fg, backgroundColor = bg)
setCellStyle(c, style)
```

Setting the max value for rgb() makes it easier to scale the color with respect to the value's range.

The xlsx package has some IMHO rough edges, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a macro inside your Excel workbook to allow dynamic changes based on the data you load into cells.  Take a look at the last answer at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4998f97b-44c2-431a-bc91-138a94b12519/how-to-dynamically-set-a-cells-background-color-based-on-value-from-another-worksheet-in-the-same for one possibility. Here's another: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/459520-dynamically-assigning-cell-rgb-background-color-using-contents-3-other-cells.html

I haven't tried these out, so you'll have to play with them to see if they meet your needs.

Edit: tripped across this SO question:  [Conditional Formatting using Excel VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661965/conditional-formatting-using-excel-vba-code)

Edit to respond to comment:
@AbinasMishra I don't understand your comment.  R cannot change the values inside Excel's Conditional Formatting dialog box, so far as I know, in any way other than having Excel run a macro.  And your claims about "additional memory" to run a macro are wrong.  If you open an Excel sheet it's going to allocate memory for all its internal objects. The time and RAM associated with running a small macro are miniscule.

Now, are you thinking of **static** cell coloring, rather than Conditional Formatting?  If you wanted to do that from R, your best bet is to have R write some integer values to a 'reference' worksheet in your workbook, and, yes, run a macro which looks up those integer values and assigns a fill color to the cells of interest.

Comment: May be i had missed something.This can be done using  macro i understand, but then the conditional formatting happens every time we open the excel sheet, which consumes additional memory in our system even if we don't change any value as it runs a check.But suppose the conditional formatting is done through R and we just get the output in excel then there would be no additional check as there  would be no background codes running. Hence, we only would be running the R code the time the values are changed and the excel sheet would only give the output.

Comment: ok. so if we want to have a static color bar, in which we just give the low and high value with the color grades say yellow(#FFD801) for 'low' and red(#FF0000) for 'high'.The values inbetween is to be automatically colored in the range between #FF0000 to #FFD801. The static color bar output has to be in the reference excel sheet.So is it possible?