# R, XLConnect: Setting color with RGB code

Tags: r, excel, rgb, xlsx, xlconnect

I have come across the following problem. A lot of data is written to an Excel file. Within the written excel table, I want to set the cell color to a non-predefined value (which is a function of the number written to the cell). E.g.: The higher the number in a given cell, the greener the cell.

I know that solutions exist for the package `xlsx` (See [HERE](http://www.r-bloggers.com/when-life-gives-you-coloured-cells-make-categories/) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356945/how-can-we-create-a-color-scales-for-excel-using-r)). But I already use `XLConnect` throughout the entire project and do not want to convert all of the code that I have so far.

Currently, I use the following code to set the cell color:

```
# create the excel workbook
wb <- loadWorkbook("FILENAME.xls", create=TRUE)`

# Create a CellStyle with yellow solid foreground
CellColor <- createCellStyle(wb)
setFillPattern(CellColor, fill = XLC$"FILL.SOLID_FOREGROUND")
setFillForegroundColor(CellColor, color = XLC$"COLOR.YELLOW")

# apply the CellStyle to a given cell, here: (10,10)
setCellStyle(wb, sheet=SHEETNAME, row=10, col=10, cellstyle=CellColor)

# save the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Obviously, the problematic part is

```
color = XLC$"COLOR.YELLOW"
```

because it does not let me set the rgb code of the color I like. Attempts like

```
color = rgb(0.2,0.4,0.8)
```

fail.

The [XLConnect documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf) on page 91 does only tell that

> The color is normally specified via a corresponding color constant from the XLC object.

There is no explanation on how to use RGB code.

Comment: RGB is currently not supported in XLConnect (as of XLConnect 0.2-13)