# Copy range then paste values to a different section of the sheet then back to the original range

Tags: excel, copy, paste

With a click of a button, I'm trying to grab a range of data, paste the values, delete the original range of data then move the values back to the original location.  Something like this...

```
ws.Range("A11:AD400").Copy
ws.Range("A511:AD900").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ws.Range("A11:AD400").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
Selection.ClearContents
ws.Range("A511:AD900").Copy
ws.Range("A11:AD400").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ws.Range("A511:AD900").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: why is the better question? And what isn't working with your code?

Comment: @J_P I'm really just looking for a clean way to perform the task.  In my opinion, this method is slow and clunky.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with copying a range, deleting it, copying back its values to the same place? What are you achieving with this that can't be done in place?

Comment: @QHarr I currently have users that paste into a sheet and it messes up the formatting. My thought was to have a repair button that could unprotect the sheet, copy all and paste values back into the range, then protect the sheet again.

Comment: Why not just have code that applied the correct formatting for the repair?

Comment: I didn't think of it that way, but love the idea.  Can you please point me in the right direction for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in effect you want to just restore correct formatting, record a macro  as your format the target range ( `ws.Range("A11:AD400")`). Then that code can be re-used as your repair code which you can run to re-format the range as you require in future (you can link to a button for example).

Much more efficient than copying and pasting and copying back when it is only the formatting that is important.

Learning to use the macro-recorder:

1. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html
2. http://www.contextures.com/excel-macro-record-test.html

Intro to range formatting:

1. http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/

Comment: This is great! thanks @ QHarr.  Is there a way to restore conditional formatting this way as well?

Comment: www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat04.html  , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661965/conditional-formatting-using-excel-vba-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Did it make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help, I ended up using this to reset the formats from a know good range.    ws.Range("A398:AD398").Copy
ws.Range("A11:AD399").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats