# Exporting access query to VBA, conditional formatting allows .AddColorScale, but not .Add

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, conditional-formatting

first time asking a question so apologies if I mess up somewhere. Usually I can find the answer on here, but not today!

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to an Excel sheet after using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet from an Access database query result. I can get .AddColorScale to work, but I want .Add xlCellValue - and I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
Sub excelExportOld()

excelName = InputBox("Name the file:")

nameofUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName

filePath = "C:\Users\" & nameofUser & "\Documents\Movers_" & excelName & ".xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acExport, SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, TableName:="Combined_movers", FileName:=filePath, HasFieldNames:=True

'open the created Excel doc
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    Set wkbk = .workbooks.Open(filePath)
End With


'format Excel doc
Set wks = wkbk.worksheets(1)
With wks

    'column width adjustments
    With .cells
        .Select
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    'format header
    .range("A1:T1").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    
    'conditional format 'Moves' column
    With .range("P:P")
        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 0
    End With
    With .range("Q:Q")
        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 0
    End With
    With .range("R:R")
    '**everything works fine up until here - now I get a debug error on the next line**
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotEqual, Formula1:="=1"
    'I've also tried:
    '.FormatConditions.Add(1, 4, "=1") // and .Add(CellValue, xlNotEqual, "=1")
    'but it doesn't seem to like any of them

        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With

End With

Set wkbk = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The debug message is 'invalid procedure call or argument'

It just seems to hate .Add for some reason, but .AddColorScale is no problem

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Formatting using Excel VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661965/conditional-formatting-using-excel-vba-code)

Comment: I'm not trying to overlap two conditional formats onto the same range - I'm just trying to get conditional formatting for .range("R:R") above to work. The formatting for "P:P" and "Q:Q" already functions perfectly.
(it still doesn't work if I delete all the P:P and Q:Q formatting, I'm just trying to show that .AddColorScale works, but .Add doesn't)

Comment: Tested your code and works for me.