# VBA messing with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I wrote the code below to archive resolved feedback issues however, when it runs although it works fine it screws with my "Traffic Light" conditional formatting. Is there a way for the code to do it's job but not effect the conditional formatting or maybe by deleting the rows after it pastes them within the VBA code itself?

Any help and advise would be greatly appreciated.

Please see the code below -

```vb
Sub ArchiveResolvedRows()

Dim wsF As Worksheet
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim lastRowF As Long
Dim lastRowA As Long
Dim i As Long

Set wsF = Worksheets("Feedback Tracker")
Set wsA = Worksheets("Archive")

lastRowF = wsF.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRowF To 2 Step -1 ' Loops through all rows in reverse order starting from the last row

    If InStr(1, wsF.Range("E" & i).Value, "Resolved", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' Checks if the value in column E contains "Resolved"

        lastRowA = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Gets the last row of sheet "Archive"

        wsF.Rows(i).Cut ' Cuts the row in the "Feedback Tracker" sheet
        wsA.Rows(lastRowA + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown ' Inserts the row in the "Archive" sheet at the last row

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain "screws with my "Traffic Light" conditional formatting." We can't tell what that is based on the detail you've provided.

Comment: Conditional formatting often screws when deleting or adding rows. I suppose it would happen even when doing the archiving manually. Best would be to apply the conditional formatting via VBA after the archiving code ran.

Comment: Thats interesting, so the formatting gets deleted when the rows cut and paste which I understand. How would I go about writing the VBA to make columns A to E in a row colour based on specific text in a cell in column E of each row?

Comment: Apply the conditional formatting as the last step of the vba.

Comment: [This should give you a starting point for conditional formatting in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661965/conditional-formatting-using-excel-vba-code)

Comment: It's not the formatting itselft that gets deleted - but the range to which the conditional formatting is applied becomes weird